# Display data at ends of floating bar graph (created using chart js)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, chart.js

I've created a floating bar graph using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/). I wanted to display the values at the ends of the bar graph (at the starting and ending points), but I'm only able to display the data at one of the ends and it looks like this ex: 120,70.

Is there any method to display the corresponding values at the ends of the bars in the chart?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the custom-labels option in chartjs-datalabels-plugin